# Error of a map made by gmapping

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run a waffle pi along a path of 60cm width.
During the test, I noticed that there is difference between a map made by gmapping and local map made during navigation.

Please see the attached image or link.
Black line is made by gmapping and green dotted line is made during navigation.
These lines are misaligned and the difference is approximately 20cm.

This phenomenon still happens after update of a Turtlebot3 package (v1.0.0) and a OpenCR firmware (v1.2.0).

Please give me your comment and/or advise.

BRs.

[Attached image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16JSP6DCZEXjJ5rT6BsP6ahj6XIIXUZp3)

[Direct link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16JSP6DCZEXjJ5rT6BsP6ahj6XIIXUZp3)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298507/error-of-a-map-made-by-gmapping/) by [taka](https://answers.ros.org/users/36336/taka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2018-07-24**:
I don't see any error in mapping. I see an offset in localization. Are you running any nodes to locate the robot in the map like AMCL?

**Comment by [taka](https://answers.ros.org/users/36336/taka/) on 2018-07-25**:
Thanks.
There is an offset between a map made by gmapping and local map made during navigation. I think this offset has a bad influence for navigation.
I'm not sure why the offset occurs and how to minimize the offset. I use AMCL particles for localization.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seams like error in odometry data or that you are running a robot without localization. Try to run AMCL node for localization. See [here](https://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [taka](https://answers.ros.org/users/36336/taka/) on 2018-07-25**:
Thanks. As shown in [rqt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q4doXae_DLwX9jG3uOX_1itp3pwqVYZJ), I run the AMCL node during navigation. As you say, there may be error in odometory data, but I don't know how I can fix it.

**Comment by [taka](https://answers.ros.org/users/36336/taka/) on 2018-07-25**:
I think there is a problem during map making. I noticed two things.

(1) When location of robot changes, results of laser scan (green dot in rviz) points to different  position. Please compare red circle in [image1](https://goo.gl/uVLfmA) and [image2](https://goo.gl/f1S47a).

**Comment by [taka](https://answers.ros.org/users/36336/taka/) on 2018-07-25**:
(2) While the robot slowly goes forward during map making, it looks like that the robot goes back and forth in rviz. Please see [video](https://goo.gl/V6W4ig). I think this is related to (1).

Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-07-26**:
this is all OK. The robot "jumps" when slam calculates data. It seams that your odometry data says that robot moves slower than it really moves. Please check your odometry data, this should be in some yaml file of your diff drive controller. It could be that your wheels are too small...

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2018-07-26**:
Also you can change the covarinance of your odometry. I am just not sure where, It should be published by your differential controller or it is defined in configuations of your slam/localization.